# Shell selects wrong python executable in virtualenv

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I have added virtualenv to the existing project and can't understand the miracle:

```
dev:/www/development$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
dev:/www/development$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/usr/bin/python3
dev:/www/development$ source env/bin/activate
(env) dev:/www/development$ echo $PATH
/www/development/env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
(env) dev:/www/development$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/usr/bin/python3
(env) dev:/www/development$ /usr/bin/env python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/www/development/env/bin/python
(env) dev:/www/development$ which python
/www/development/env/bin/python
...
(env) dev:/www/development$ hash -r
(env) dev:/www/development$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/usr/bin/python3
(env) dev:/www/development$ hash
hash: hash table empty
(env) dev:/www/development$ type python
python is aliased to `/usr/bin/python3'
(env) dev:/www/development$ man python
(env) dev:/www/development$ hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/man
```

On the other host with the same configuration everything works as expected. What am I missing? Why does the shell select wrong executable?

**Update (problem found)**

Thanks to @iBug pointing me out to `type python` command. After some thinking I have noticed that I have alias for python in `/etc/profile` left there from some ancient time:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Bash (which I suppose so because you tagged your question with Bash), this will do it:

```
hash -r
```

Then try again with `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`.

---

If you're wondering what it's doing, try

```
type python
```

(note: `type` is a shell builtin whereas `which` is usually a standalone program)